# Adding button to QGIS toolbar by using Python and Macros in Project Properties

Tags: qgis, python, toolbar

I've successfully created a script that adds a button to the plugin toolbar in QGIS, by running the script in the python console.

Here is my code:

```
import webbrowser
icon_path = MyPath

def open_url():
webbrowser.open(MyURL)

action = QAction(name)
action.triggered.connect(open_url)
action.setIcon(QIcon(icon_path))
iface.addToolBarIcon(action)
```

I have read that you can make QGIS to add the button when a certain QGIS project is loaded by using 'Project properties' -> 'Macros'.

Though, This won't work for me.

What I have tried is...:

```
import webbrowser
from qgis.PyQt.QtGui import *
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import *
from qgis.utils import iface

def openProject():

url = 'https://google.dk'

def show_url():
    iface.messageBar().pushMessage()
    webbrowser.open(url, new=1)

action = QAction('Show Time')
action.triggered.connect(show_url)
action.setIcon(QIcon(MyPath)
iface.addToolBarIcon(action)
```

Can anybode figure out what I am missing in the code for make the Macro work out well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you check that macro execution is enabled in QGIS settings?

[image]

Besides, there's some problem with your code:

- Wrong indentation (after `def openProject():`)
- Missing parenthesis `action.setIcon(QIcon(MyPath))`
- Missing parameter `iface.messageBar().pushMessage(f"Open {url}")`
- Undefined variable `MyPath`
- You may want to remove the action when the project is closed

Here is what your macro script may look like

```
import webbrowser
from qgis.PyQt.QtGui import QIcon
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QAction
from qgis.utils import iface

url = 'https://google.dk'
iconPath = ':/images/themes/default/mIconWms.svg'

def show_url():
    iface.messageBar().pushMessage("Showing URL")
    webbrowser.open(url, new=1)

action = QAction(QIcon(iconPath), 'Show Time')
action.triggered.connect(show_url)

def openProject():
    iface.addToolBarIcon(action)

def saveProject():
    pass

def closeProject():
    action.deleteLater()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Works perfect! Best, Kristoffer